# Custom awaitables for dummies

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

In [Async/Await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx), Stephen Toub says:

> An **awaitable** is any type that exposes a `GetAwaiter` method which returns a valid *awaiter*.
>   ...
>   An **awaiter** is *any* type returned from an *awaitable*’s `GetAwaiter` method and that conforms to a particular pattern.

So in order to be an *awaiter*, a type should:

- Implement the [`INotifyCompletion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion.aspx) interface.
- Provide a boolean property called `IsCompleted`.
- Provide a parameterless `GetResult` method that returns `void` or `TResult`.

(*I'm ignoring `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` for now.*)

I know the page I mentioned has a sample that shows how the compiler translates await operations but I'm stil having a hard time understanding.

When I *await* an *awaitable*,

- When is `IsCompleted` checked? Where should I set it?
- When is `OnCompleted` called?
- Which thread calls `OnCompleted`?
- I saw examples of both directly invoking the continuation parameter of `OnCompleted` and using `Task.Run(continuation)` in different examples, which should I go for and why?

Comment: FWIW, I found his 'await anything' post helpful on this level. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115642.aspx

Comment: @James: Nice reference, thank you.

Comment: @JamesManning the link expired, see update: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why would you want a custom awaiter?

You can see the compiler's interpretation of `await` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx). Essentially:

```
var temp = e.GetAwaiter();
if (!temp.IsCompleted)
{
  SAVE_STATE()
  temp.OnCompleted(&cont);
  return;

cont:
  RESTORE_STATE()
}
var i = temp.GetResult();
```

**Edit from comments:** `OnCompleted` should schedule its argument as a continuation of the asynchronous operation.

Comment: No particular reason, I just want to know how it works. Though I still don't get the compiler's interpretation of await (sorry) does it call OnCompleted on parallel or should I provide an asynchronous implementation? (When will you do some awaitable socket posts by the way?)

Comment: `OnCompleted` is used to schedule the rest of the method as a continuation. So your implementation would just add it as a continuation to your asynchronous operation. And I'm working on the awaitable sockets... :)

Comment: Well, the awaiter has to run the continuation *somewhere*. If you don't care about synchronization context, using `Task.Run()` might make sense. Ignoring the context would be unusual, but if it was a common situation, you wouldn't be creating a custom awaiter in the first place.

Comment: @svick: OK, I can see the reasoning in that.

Answer (score 5):

In the vast majority of cases, you as a developer need not worry about this. Use the `async` and `await` keywords and the compiler and runtime handle all this for you.

To answer your questions:

> When does the code checks IsCompleted? Where should I set it?

The task should set `IsCompleted` when the task has finished doing what it was doing. For example, if the task was loading data from a file, `IsCompleted` should return true when the data is loaded and the caller can access it.

> When does it calls OnCompleted?

OnCompleted usually contains a delegate supplied by the caller to execute when the task has completed.

> Does it call OnCompleted in parallel or should the code 
>   inside OnCompleted be asynchronous?

The code in OnCompleted should be thread neutral (not care which thread it is called from). This may be problematic for updating COM objects in Single Threaded Apartments (like any UI classes in Metro/Windows8/Windows Store apps). It does not have to be asynchronous but may contain asynchronous code.

> I saw examples of both directly invoking the continuation parameter of OnCompleted 
>   and using Task.Run(continuation) in different examples, which should I go for and when?

Use `async`/`await` when you can. Otherwise, use Task.Run() or Task.Wait() because they follow the sequential programming model most people are used to. Using continuations may still be required, particularly in Metro apps where you have apartment issues.

Comment: `Set IsCompleted when the task has finished doing what it was doing.` So when to start doing what it should be doing? In the constructor? In `OnCompleted`?

Comment: The awaiter should wait until IsCompleted is true and OnCompleted has been called. The task should do what it needs to do by whatever means is appropriate, usually on a different thread and/or using a ThreadPool.

Comment: @ŞafakGür That depends on what your awaiter is supposed to do. But a constructor sounds like a reasonable choice.